# Measure of convex hull

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $ a_0,...,a_n\in \mathbb{R}^n $ and define the convex hull with $$ S_A:=\text{conv}(\{a_0,...,a_n\})=\left \{\lambda_0\cdot a_0+...+\lambda_n\cdot a_n\Big|\ \  \lambda_0,...,\lambda_n\geq 0, \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k=1 \right \}. $$

If the vectors $ a_0,...,a_n $ are linearly independent I could show the identity $$ \lambda^n(S_A)=\frac{1}{n!}\cdot |\det((a_1-a_0,...,a_n-a_0))| $$
I used a linear isomorphism.
But how do I show $ \lambda^n(S_A)=0 $ if some of the vectors $ a_0,...,a_n $ are linear dependent?

Comment: Any lower dimensional subspace has Lebesgue measure $0$ as a consequence of Fubini's Theorem.

Comment: I don't see how Fubini's Theorem should help to get 0.

Comment: $M=\{x_1,x_2,..,x_k,0,0,...,0)$ has measure $0$ by Fubini and any $k-$ dimensional space is $T(M)$ for some linear isometry $T$. $T$ preserves Lebesgue measure.

Comment: How do you apply Fubini here???